# How to align baselines of 2 side-by-side Divs?

Tags: css

This is a page from [my blog](http://goo.gl/ZbJR6p).
I have created a gray colored box titled *Journal entries*.

The Point 1 reads as *For recording...*
As you can see, the text starting from the word *For* is slightly below the level of the number *1*.
Same is the case with Point 2.

Please suggest what changes should I make to the code.

My code:

```
<div style="background-color: #F0F0F0; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 15px;">
    <div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 100px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;">


        <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: georgia; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">Journal entries</span></div>

        <br>


        <div style="font-family: serif; font-size: 17px; margin-left: 30px;">

            <div style="float: left;">1.&nbsp;</div>
            <div>For recording 1<sup>st</sup> aspect, asset value is reduced period-wise by crediting its account:</div>
            <div style="margin-left: 20px;">Depreciation A/c&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...Dr.
                <br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To Asset A/c</div>

            <br>

            <div style="float: left;">2.&nbsp;</div>
            <div>For recording 2<sup>nd</sup> aspect, the depreciation for the period is transferred to the Profit &amp; Loss Account:</div>
            <div style="margin-left: 20px;">Profit and Loss A/c&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...Dr.
                <br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To Depreciation A/c</div>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you don't want the text to go below the number at all.  One option would be to place the number within the text `div` and then position it absolutely in the corner.  Then add a bit of padding to the div to move the text over.:

```
<div class="text">
    <div class="num">
        1.
    </div>

    stuff
</div>
```

```
.text{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.num{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 20px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/THYga/1/

Comment: Thanks James and Green, But i don't want the text to come below numbers. So, the numbers at left and the text at right should be at 2 separate levels and don't be mixed or wrapped together.

Comment: @rohitmakkar  That was unclear from your question.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SPAN` instead of `DIV` elements. if you can't change the html then assign `display: inline` to those `DIV` elements using CSS. and also don't use `float: left` to the numbering element.